# Is there any limitation on number of data rows for Google Motion Chart?

Tags: javascript, flash, charts, google-visualization

I have a weird problem with Google motion charts, they work fine when I have small number of data rows, but when I have more (like 8000) they act weird. They start slow by showing the actual data but suddenly shows wrong data for wrong time units. Data are only for 160 time units but for many experiments. I used the exact code as the example provided for Motion chart but with my own data.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
        data.addRows([
          ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
          ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Motion Chart example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#Example)

Comment: The limitation is your machine..

Comment: Thanks @AliGajani , How can I resolve it ? I think I have enough RAM 8gb and a good CPU. 3.4GH i5